# brew install freetds --with-unixodbc fails

Tags: python, homebrew, freetds, unixodbc

Has anyone seen this happen to them when running `brew install freetds --with-unixodbc`?

```
$ brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.00.26.tar.bz2

curl: (56) response reading failed
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://fossies.org/linux/privat/freetds-1.00.26.tar.bz2

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 410 Gone
Error: Failed to download resource "freetds"
Download failed: https://fossies.org/linux/privat/freetds-1.00.26.tar.bz2
```

Any help or pointers for this would be great. thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means you're trying to dl a file that isn't there! I'm betting `brew` hasn't updated to point to the new one yet. You can see that an error is given if you go [directly to the page](https://fossies.org/linux/privat/freetds-1.00.26.tar.bz2).

Comment: @eijen yes the fossies pages is missing, but the original ftp link that it tries is there, because I can download it directly if I want...but for some reason brew is erroring out there. any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer to this question by posting an issue on the homebrew github page. Here's ilovezfs's answer:

> you can try this link
>   https://distfiles.macports.org/freetds/freetds-1.00.26.tar.bz2 and
>   place the file in ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew.

So through this I learned that a workaround to brew links not working (mine didn't work bc of a firewall I have in place on my computer), you can also download the source files, drop it into the Homebrew directory, and run:

```
brew install <library name>
```

Just wanted to post this answer in case it is useful to someone out there with a similar issue.